# nginx ssl3_get_record wrong version number 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am deploying an Ingress on my K8S cluster. All my configs look good.

My Ingress is defined like this :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "false"
  creationTimestamp: 2018-10-20T23:40:47Z
  generation: 1
  labels:
    type: jenkins
  name: jenkins-ingress
  namespace: helm-gcp-test-jenkins
  resourceVersion: "59946"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/helm-gcp-test-jenkins/ingresses/jenkins-tls
  uid: 91c5fd22-d4c1-11e8-a0e9-6691b5512bd6
spec:
  rules:
  - host: master.ingress.proj.csp-test.shoo.company.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: jenkins-master
          servicePort: 8090
        path: /
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.187.16.8
```

The deployed Ingress looks like :

```
NAME          HOSTS                                                  ADDRESS         PORTS     AGE
jenkins   master.ingress.proj.csp-test.shoo.company.com  
35.187.16.8   80        21m
```

Since I'm deploying this in GCP, I have a LB as well.

As you can see the Ingress is supposed to route traffic to `jenkins-master` on port `8090`

This service is present in the same namespace.

```
# kubectl get -n helm-gcp-test-jenkins svc jenkins-master
NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)              AGE
jenkins-master   ClusterIP   100.71.2.206   <none>        8090/TCP,30005/TCP   13m
```

From within the cluster if I do `curl http://100.71.2.206:8090`, I can successfully see the main page of my application, which means that setup is OK.

Now when I try to access the Ingress from my Browser, this is all that I see.

[image]

When I look at the logs of my Ingress controller pod, they have the following ERROR:

```
2018/10/20 23:44:05 [error] 1084#1084: *538 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.250.0.2, server: master.ingress.proj.csp-test.shoo.company.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://100.96.0.35:8090/", host: "master.ingress.proj.csp-test.shoo.company.com"
10.250.0.2 - [10.250.0.2] - - [20/Oct/2018:23:44:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 174 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Safari/605.1.15" 438 0.002 [helm-gcp-test-jenkins-jenkins-master-8090] 100.96.0.35:8090 0 0.002 502 60a2a0827ecfa7f0f43997c3b90e5eea
2018/10/20 23:44:06 [error] 1084#1084: *542 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.250.0.2, server: master.ingress.proj.csp-test.shoo.company.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://100.96.0.35:8090/favicon.ico", host: "master.ingress.proj.csp-test.shoo.company.com", referrer: "http://master.ingress.proj.csp-test.shoo.company.com/"
10.250.0.2 - [10.250.0.2] - - [20/Oct/2018:23:44:06 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 174 "http://master.ingress.proj.csp-test.shoo.company.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0 Safari/605.1.15" 447 0.003 [helm-gcp-test-jenkins-jenkins-master-8090] 100.96.0.35:8090 0 0.002 502 80769268e1fe1fccd33ed2b58720672e
```

Not sure what this error is. Any ideas ? Am I using the wrong Annotations ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at theofficial [List of Annotation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md).

There is no `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"`. Also, you use the HTTP in this case you don't need to `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: true"`.

> The annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough`
>   instructs the controller to send TLS connections directly to the
>   backend instead of letting NGINX decrypt the communication. See also
>   [TLS/HTTPS](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough)
>   in the User guide.
>   !!! note SSL Passthrough is **disabled by default** and requires
>   starting the controller with the
>   [`--enable-ssl-passthrough`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/cli-arguments)
>   flag.
>   !!! attention Because SSL Passthrough works on layer 4 of the OSI
>   model (TCP) and not on the layer 7 (HTTP), using SSL Passthrough
>   invalidates all the other annotations set on an Ingress object.

Make sure you enable ssl-passthrough in controller, or you can remove this annotation since you don't use the SSL.